# Sybase ASE 12.0 CSV Table Export

Tags: csv, sap-ase, bcp, export-to-csv

What I'm trying to do is export a view/table from Sybase ASE 12.0 into a CSV file, but I'm having a lot of difficulty in it.

We want to import it into [IDEA](http://www.audimation.com/about.cfm) or MS-Access. The way that these programs operate is with the text-field encapsulation character and a field separator character, along with new lines being the record separator (without being able to modify this).

Well, using `bcp` to export it is ultimately fruitless with its built in options. It doesn't allow you to define a text field encapsulation character (as far as I can tell). So we tried to create another view that reads from the other view/table that concatenates the fields that have new lines in them (`text` fields), however, you may not do that without losing some of the precision because it forces the field into a `varchar` of 8000 characters/bytes, of which our max field used is 16000 (so there's definitely some truncation).

So, we decided to create columns in the new view that had the text field delimiters. However, that put our column count for the view at 320 -- 70 more than the 250 column limit in ASE 12.0.

`bcp` can only work on existing tables and views, so what can we do to export this data? We're pretty much open to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its only the new line char that is causing problems can you not just do a replace

```
create new view as
select field1, field2, replace(text_field_with_char, 'new line char,' ' ')
from old_view
```

You may have to consider exporting as 2 files, importing into your target as 2 tables and then combining them again in the target.  If both files have a primary key this is simple.

Comment: Replacing the new line characters with spaces really destroys the readability of those fields for the person who's going to use it, unfortunately.

Comment: You could replace with an otherwise unused character.  Export/import and then replace the otherwise unused char back to a line break

Comment: So we ended up going with your initial suggestion. I'm sure there's a better way though. We even tried using the unused character as a text encapsulator, but the programs didn't want to play nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like bcp's right, but process the output via awk or perl.
But are those things you have and know?  That might be a little overhead for you.
If you're on Windows you can get Active Perl free and it could be quick.

something like:

perl -F, -lane 'print "\"$F[0]\",$F[1],\"$F[2]\",$F[3]\n" ;' bcp-output-file

how's that?  $F is an array of fields.  The text ones you encircle with \"

Answer (score 0):

You can use BCP format files for this.

bcp .... -f XXXX.fmt

BCP can also produce this format files interactively if you don't state 
any of -c -n -f flags. Then you can save the format file and experiment with it, editing it and runnign BCP.
To safe time while exporting and debugging, use -F -L flags like "-F 1 -L 10" -- this gets only first 10 lines.